# Writing to IMU via usb port freezes

Tags: c, usb

I have an IMU sensor that i'm trying to read its data via usb port. i'm using ubuntu 11.10 and eclipse IDE. the language used is C. to do this i must send a specific command code to IMU and read the result. i have already done this but my problem is that when i want to read data from IMU in an infinite loop (read data as many times as i want), the write function (which i use to send command to IMU) freezes. that is program execution stops in write function.

Here's the code:

```
int comport = -1; // Handle COM port
struct termios options;

comport = open("/dev/ttyACM0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);

fcntl(comport, F_SETFL, 0);

//Get the current options for the port...
tcgetattr(comport, &options);

cfsetispeed(&options, B115200);
cfsetospeed(&options, B115200);

options.c_cflag |= CS8;
options.c_oflag &= ~OPOST; //raw output

//Enable the receiver and set local mode...
options.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);

//Set the new options for the port...
tcsetattr(comport, TCSANOW, &options);

//read compass 0x23
char command[] = {0xF7, 0x23, 0x23};

while(1)
{
bytes_written = write(comport, command, 3);

if(bytes_written == -1)
{
        printf("\nsending command to IMU failed!");
        //...
}
else if(bytes_written == 3)
{
  //sending command OK

  bytes_read = read(comport,  // Handle
                    INBUFFER, // Incoming data
                12        // Number of bytes to read
                );
}
} //end while(1)
```